# Cambiar valor vacio de una colunma por otra en pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lo que sucede es que la columna de ciudades izquierda tiene campos vacios que necesito llenar con los que no lo estan en la colunma de ciudades derecha pero no se como hacerlo y ya intente con esta funcion pero esta mal y no se si pueden darme alguna sugerencia o ayuda para poder poner en esos campos que por ejemplo hay dos vacios en la izquierda que ambos a la derecha son de BOGOTA, entonces tendria que rellanar en la columna de la izquierda por esos dos valores.

```
def rellenar_vacias(ciudad_izq,ciudad_der):
if ciudad_izq == '' and ciudad_der != '':
    return ciudad_der
```

Muchas gracias, me salvarian

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` como texto para que podamos copiar y pegar la información

Comment: No entendí. Se supone que la imagen es la referencia porque estoy manejando una cantidad de datos muy grande

Comment: Por eso mencioné algunas filas, por ejemplo 10. Los datos siempre deben ir como texto ya que como imagen no podemos copiar y utilizar la información

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La forma más fácil que se me ocurre es utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Como no incluiste los datos como texto, cree un ejemplo genérico con el siguiente `dataframe` en un archivo llamado "sample2.csv"

```
    A   B
0   1.0 1.0
1   2.0 NaN
2   NaN 3.0
3   4.0 4.0
4   5.0 NaN
5   NaN 6.0
```

Al utilizar `fillna` seleccionamos la columna que deseamos utilizar para rellenar los datos faltantes

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df['A'].fillna(df['B'], inplace=True)
```

Al imprimir `df` obtenemos:

```
    A   B
0   1.0 1.0
1   2.0 NaN
2   3.0 3.0
3   4.0 4.0
4   5.0 NaN
5   6.0 6.0
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias me funciono con lo que necesitaba